# How to exclude elements with zero values -XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have list of 100+ elements for which I'm doing mapping. I want to check each element if it contains any "0" values. If it contains zero values then I should eliminate that particular element from output where ever present in that input document.
Here is my below sample xml:

```
<xml>
<xmls>
<A>0.00</A>
<B>0</B>
<C>123</C>
</xmls>
</xml>
```

I'm storing the values of elements in a variable and writing like this in my xslt for each element:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($C) > 0">
<Z>123</Z>
</xsl:if>
```

I have also tried:

```
<xsl:template match="xmls[not(string()]"/>
```

It's difficult to write this condition to each and every element, is their any other way to do this for the entire document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . = 0]"/>
```

if you want to remove all elements having the numeric value `0`.